# How to split a one field file in a multiple fields file with linux comand awks?

Tags: awk

I have the following file `list.txt`:

```
AbateI.       D
AcatulloM.    A
AcerbiF.      D
AcquafrescaR. A
AcquahA.      C
AdjapongC.    D
AdnanA.       D
AdrianoL.     A
AjetiA.       D
AlbiolR.      D
AldeganiG.    P
AleesamiH.    D
AlexSandro    D
AlissonR.     P
```

And I want rearrange the file with `awk` to group them by the second column to look like this:

```
P                    D              C                 A
AldeganiG.         AbateI.         AcquahA.         AcatulloM. 
AlissonR.          AcerbiF.                         AcquafrescaR.
                   AdjapongC.                       AdrianoL. 
                   AdnanA. 
                   AjetiA. 
                   AlbiolR. 
                   AleesamiH.
                   AlexSandro
```

This is what I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
FORMAT="\t%-20s%-20s%-20s%s\n"
printf FORMAT,"P","D","C","A"
}

($2=="P")  {a[$1] = $1}
($2=="D")  {b[$1] = $1}
($2=="C")  {c[$1] = $1}
($2=="A")  {d[$1] = $1}

END{for(i in a) printf FORMAT, a[i],"","",""}
```

But I don't know how to loop and print other arrays.

Comment: Create 4 arrays, and add `$1` to the array that corresponds to `$2`. Then at the end, print an element from each array on the line, and keep looping until you run out of entries in the longest array.

Comment: @Barmar I will write it, if I find the problem interesting, as I do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` and `column` with some process substitution:

```
$ paste \
      <(awk '/P$/ {print $1}'<input) \
      <(awk '/D$/ {print $1}'<input) \
      <(awk '/C$/ {print $1}'<input) \
      <(awk '/A$/ {print $1}'<input) | column -s $'\t' -t
AldeganiG.  AbateI.     AcquahA.  AcatulloM.
AlissonR.   AcerbiF.              AcquafrescaR.
            AdjapongC.            AdrianoL.
            AdnanA.
            AjetiA.
            AlbiolR.
            AleesamiH.
            AlexSandro
```

Add the column headers manually, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    rowNr = ++numColRows[$2]
    val[rowNr,$2] = $1
    numRows = (rowNr > numRows ? rowNr : numRows)
}
END {
    for (colName in numColRows) {
        printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), colName
    }
    print ""
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        c = 0
        for (colName in numColRows) {
            printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), val[rowNr,colName]
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
A              P           C         D
AcatulloM.     AldeganiG.  AcquahA.  AbateI.
AcquafrescaR.  AlissonR.             AcerbiF.
AdrianoL.                            AdjapongC.
                                     AdnanA.
                                     AjetiA.
                                     AlbiolR.
                                     AleesamiH.
                                     AlexSandro
```

Read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep-cut-paste-expand` combination too

```
paste \
   <(echo "P";grep 'P$' list.txt |cut -d ' ' -f1 ) \
   <(echo "D";grep 'D$' list.txt |cut -d ' ' -f1 ) \
   <(echo "C";grep 'C$' list.txt |cut -d ' ' -f1 ) \
   <(echo "A";grep 'A$' list.txt |cut -d ' ' -f1) | expand -t 20
```

**Output**

```
P                   D                   C                   A
AldeganiG.          AbateI.             AcquahA.            AcatulloM.
AlissonR.           AcerbiF.                                AcquafrescaR.
                    AdjapongC.                              AdrianoL.
                    AdnanA.                                 
                    AjetiA.                                 
                    AlbiolR.                                
                    AleesamiH.                              
                    AlexSandro
```

You could replace `grep-cut` with `sed` as shown below

```
paste \
    <(echo "P";sed -n '/P$/{s/[[:blank:]]*P$//;p}' file ) \
    <(echo "D";sed -n '/D$/{s/[[:blank:]]*D$//;p}' file ) \
    <(echo "C";sed -n '/C$/{s/[[:blank:]]*C$//;p}' file ) \
    <(echo "A";sed -n '/A$/{s/[[:blank:]]*A$//;p}' file ) | expand -t 20
```

**Output**

```
P                   D                   C                   A
AldeganiG.          AbateI.             AcquahA.            AcatulloM.
AlissonR.           AcerbiF.                                AcquafrescaR.
                    AdjapongC.                              AdrianoL.
                    AdnanA.                                 
                    AjetiA.                                 
                    AlbiolR.                                
                    AleesamiH.                              
                    AlexSandro
```

You could also do it this way

```
paste \
     <(awk 'BEGIN{print "P"}/P$/{print $1}' file )
     <(awk 'BEGIN{print "D"}/D$/{print $1}' file )
     <(awk 'BEGIN{print "C"}/C$/{print $1}' file )
     <(awk 'BEGIN{print "A"}/A$/{print $1}' file ) | expand -t 20
```

**Ouput**

```
P                   D                   C                   A
AldeganiG.          AbateI.             AcquahA.            AcatulloM.
AlissonR.           AcerbiF.                                AcquafrescaR.
                    AdjapongC.                              AdrianoL.
                    AdnanA.                                 
                    AjetiA.                                 
                    AlbiolR.                                
                    AleesamiH.                              
                    AlexSandro
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a non-traditional approach

```
$ awk -v OFS='\n' '{a[$2]=a[$2] OFS $1; 
                    c[$2]++; 
                    if(c[$2]>max) max=c[$2]} 
                END{pr="pr -"length(c)"t"; 
                    for(k in a) 
                       {print k a[k] | pr; 
                        for(i=c[k];i<max;i++) 
                           {print ""  | pr}}}'

A                 P                 C                 D
AcatulloM.        AldeganiG.        AcquahA.          AbateI.
AcquafrescaR.     AlissonR.                           AcerbiF.
AdrianoL.                                             AdjapongC.
                                                      AdnanA.
                                                      AjetiA.
                                                      AlbiolR.
                                                      AleesamiH.
                                                      AlexSandro
```

note that the order of the columns is somewhat arbitrary but the values are listed in insertion order.

Also this approach is not following the traditional "transpose" method with two dimensional arrays.  Perhaps better to learn that instead.

This site has many answers already for almost the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with awk 4.0 2D arrays - allows output of any number of groups in any order

```
# output order of groups
order=$*
awk -vorderstr="$order" '
BEGIN { split(orderstr, order) }
{
# grpnames[group][index]=name
  grpnames[$2][grpi[$2]++]=$1
# track max group size
  if(grpi[$2] > maxgrpsz)
    maxgrpsz=grpi[$2]
}
END {
# print groups header in order
printf("%-20s", order[1])
for(j=2; j <= length(order); ++j) {
  printf("\t%-20s", order[j])
}
printf("\n")
for(i=0; i < maxgrpsz; ++i) {
# run across each group in output order
  printf("%-20s", grpnames[order[1]][i])
  for(j=2; j <= length(order); ++j) {
    grp=order[j]
    printf("\t%-20s", grpnames[grp][i])
  }
  printf("\n")
}
}
'
```

tested

```
./myscr.sh P D C A <in.txt
P                       D                       C                       A
AldeganiG.              AbateI.                 AcquahA.                AcatulloM.
AlissonR.               AcerbiF.                                        AcquafrescaR.
                        AdjapongC.                                      AdrianoL.
                        AdnanA.
                        AjetiA.
                        AlbiolR.
                        AleesamiH.
                        AlexSandro
./myscr.sh D A P C <in.txt
D                       A                       P                       C
AbateI.                 AcatulloM.              AldeganiG.              AcquahA.
AcerbiF.                AcquafrescaR.           AlissonR.
AdjapongC.              AdrianoL.
AdnanA.
AjetiA.
AlbiolR.
AleesamiH.
AlexSandro

./myscr.sh A P <in.txt
A                       P
AcatulloM.              AldeganiG.
AcquafrescaR.           AlissonR.
AdrianoL.
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk:

```
$ cat > list.awk
{
    n=(n<++b[$2]?b[$2]:n)                # n is the max count of words in one group
    a[$2][b[$2]]=$1                      # put words to two dimensional array
} 
END {
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {                  # from 1 to n
        for(j in a)                      # for all groups
            printf "%14-s%s",a[j][i],OFS # print a word
        printf "%s",ORS                  # ORS in the end
    }
}
$ -f list.awk list.txt
AcatulloM.     AldeganiG.     AcquahA.       AbateI.        
AcquafrescaR.  AlissonR.                     AcerbiF.       
AdrianoL.                                    AdjapongC.     
                                             AdnanA.        
                                             AjetiA.        
                                             AlbiolR.       
                                             AleesamiH.     
                                             AlexSandro
```